# Blazor equivalent of WPF ShowDialog()?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm attempting to migrate some code from WPF to Blazor.  The WPF code relied on ShowDialog() to display a modal dialog and suspend execution until the modal was closed.  Is there a (server-side) Blazor equivalent that allows C# flow of control to be based, for example, on whether the user clicked Acknowledge vs Cancel in a modal dialog?

Comment: I wrote it but now is out of date :( take a look, if it looks useful I can upgrade it for current blazor version https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/BlazorConfirm

Comment: Thank you, @daniherrera.  However, I am specifically looking to avoid restructuring the code after the modal as an 'on success' and 'on failure' continuations.  The reason I have this constraint is the thousands of ways my existing code base relies on the specific behavior of WPF's ShowDialog() method.

For good or ill, we have lots of instances that are conceptually like:
    if (FileDialog.GetFilePath(out string path)) WriteOutput(path);
or
   if (CouponDialog.BuyerHasCoupon(out Coupon coupon))
   {
       order.AddCoupon();
   }
   order.PlaceOrder();

Answer (score 15):

You can add a button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"
  @onclick="AddNewForecast">
  Add New Forecast
</button>
```

That calls a method that sets a value to be true

```
bool ShowPopup = false;
void AddNewForecast()
{
    // Open the Popup
    ShowPopup = true;
}
```

And that value is wrapped around code that uses the bootstrap modal control (class="modal"):

```
        @if (ShowPopup)
        {
            <!-- This is the popup to create or edit a forecast -->
            <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" style="display:block" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h3 class="modal-title">Edit Forecast</h3>
                            <!-- Button to close the popup -->
                            <button type="button" class="close"
                                    @onclick="ClosePopup">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">X</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Edit form for the current forecast -->
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text"
                                   placeholder="Celsius forecast"
                                   @bind="objWeatherForecast.TemperatureC" />
                            <input class="form-control" type="text"
                                   placeholder="Fahrenheit forecast"
                                   @bind="objWeatherForecast.TemperatureF" />
                            <input class="form-control" type="text"
                                   placeholder="Summary"
                                   @bind="objWeatherForecast.Summary" />
                            <br />
                            <!-- Button to save the forecast -->
                            <button class="btn btn-primary"
                                    @onclick="SaveForecast">
                                Save
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

You will have a popup that is "modal"

Comment: I would guess this will fulfill his purpose. But when he uses WPF he most probably uses MVVM and thus usually you have some code in view models that say `ShowMessage` and which proceeds after that dialog. So this is a slight difference in flow of the code. Maybe it is also a difference when thinking about division of view and logic division.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, there is no out-of-the-box equivalent like in WPF.
But some good documentented samples regarding this:

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/creating-a-reusable-javascript-free-blazor-modal

https://www.syncfusion.com/blazor-components/blazor-modal-dialog

The only question for me is how to animate this kind of Dialog, e.g. with fly in / fade in animation and such things...

Answer (score -1):

The best way to port a WPF or WinForms application to Blazor is to use Nevron Open Vision for Blazor:

https://www.nevron.com/products-open-vision.aspx

It allows you to develop User Interfaces that run on Blazor and WPF/WinForms from a single code base! No HTML or JS knowledge is required either - you simply code your UI in C#.